# date::make_zoned() crashes in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, c++-chrono

I am developing a cross-platform application for which I am using [`date.h`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library using Visual Studio 2022 under Windows and GCC 11 under Linux. I know that Visual Studio C++20 has the date library integrated itself but unfortunately, I cannot use it and have to use `date.h` library for my application.

The library is imported using cmake `date::date date::date-tz`.

The following code snippet works correctly in Linux but it crashes with the error `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library` with the message `abort() has been called` when it calls `date::make_zoned` in Windows.

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto utc = time_point_cast<microseconds>(system_clock::now());
auto chicago = date::make_zoned("America/Chicago", utc);
auto local = date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(), utc);
```

Could someone kindly help me out?

Comment: Did you see the note that `tz.cpp` needs to be compiled if you want to use `tz.h`, which is presumably used to get your `America/Chicago` time zone?

Comment: Here are my recommended instructions for compiling on Windows: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation

Comment: Does it crash in the `zoned_time` constructor, or in `current_zone()`?

Comment: Is there any terminal message associated with the crash?

Comment: If you put everything under a `try`-`catch` and catch a `std::exception const&`, does it catch an exception, and if so, what does the `what()` say?

Comment: `try`-`catch` exception says `Timezone database not found at "C:\Users\01258\Downloads\tzdata"`. I have installed the library using `vcpkg`.

Comment: Ok, good detective work.  The library looked and did not find the timezone database at `"C:\Users\01258\Downloads\tzdata"`.  This is something you must install, or if you configure the lib to use `curl`, it will install for you automatically.  Details are at https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation.  I don't know what `vcpkg` did, but whatever it did, it didn't do it right.

Comment: Note that on Windows using the latest MSVC, you have the recommended option of using C++20 which has this date lib in namespace std::chrono.